# Log-Log plot of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to make a log-log plot with pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x =  10**arange(1, 10)
y = 10** arange(1,10)*2
df1 = pd.DataFrame( data=y, index=x )
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'x': x, 'y': y})
df1.plot(logy=True, logx=True)
```

[image: df1.plot(logy=True, logx=True)]

How can I make the x-axis logarithmic?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When trying to create a log-log plot using the `pandas` [plot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) function you must select [`loglog=True`](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/visualization.html#scales) rather than `logx=True, logy=True` within your keyword-arguments.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = 10 ** np.arange(1, 10)
y = 10 ** np.arange(1, 10) * 2

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=y, index=x)

df1.plot(loglog=True, legend=False)

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: @Ffisgeydd Did you get a log-log plot from my example?

Comment: @sjdh Rather than using `logx=True, logy=True` instead use `loglog=True` and it works fine :)

Comment: @Ffisgeydd Thanks. I'm new to Python Is this documented somewhere? I could not find it in the Pandas documentation. I did find something about loglog plots in the matplotlib documentation, but I don't know how to apply this to a Pandas dataframe.

Comment: It is not mentioned in the plot documentation but it is mentioned in a tutorial as I've linked in my answer.